# Windows Phone 8 geolocation returns nothing

Tags: c#, geolocation, windows-phone-8, async-await

I'm creating an app that has "what's near me" type functionality and I've got some code to find the location of the user.

I'm finding though that the call gets made but the async never seems to return.

The code I'm using is:

```
GeoCoordinate coord;
private async void GetNearMe()
{
    try
    {
        Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
        Geoposition geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();

        coord = geoposition.Coordinate.ToGeoCoordinate();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        <snip>
    }
}
```

But the code only sometimes gets to the "coord = " line (and returns correct data). If it does, it probably won't again for some reason.
Also it never gets to the catch block if it doesn't work. It just seems to hang.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong/a better way of doing it?

- I'm using Caliburn Micro and this is in the ViewModel which gets called OnActivate.
- I've tried it on the emulator and my Lumia 920 and it happens on both.
- I've tried turning Location Services off and on again with no change.

Comment: I have noticed, that this particular `await` call (on the `Geolocator`) can take a *long* time to return, no idea why. You might want to subscribe to the [`PositionChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.positionchanged.aspx) and see how that works...

Comment: The only difference I have is suffixing `GetGeopositionAsync()` with `AsTask(CancellationToken)`, can't offer much else I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

You should never use methods with an `async void` signature unless you are writing an asynchronous event handler. Such methods can't be awaited and any exceptions thrown inside them are not returned to their caller. Such exceptions are NOT caught by the exception handler. They are propagated to the unhandled exception handler of the thread that runs them.

In fact, the "[Async Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)" article in the latest edition of MSDN Magazine covers mentions exactly this case:

> ... any exceptions thrown out of an async Task method will be raised directly on the SynchronizationContext that was active when the async void method started. Figure 2 illustrates that exceptions thrown from async void methods can’t be caught naturally...

Instead of `async void` you should return `async Task`.

Answer (score 0):

Use GeoCoordinateWatcher instead,

```
GeoCoordinate coord;    
GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
    watcher.PositionChanged += (s,ea) =>
    {
    coord = new Geocoordinate(ea.Position.Location.Latitude, ea.Position.Location.Longitude);

    }
```